# Why can't we fetch @Value during JUnit execution and how to set the @Value during JUnit execution in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

How to fetch `@Value` during JUnit execution

Example:

```java
public class Test {

   @Value("${value}")
   private String value;

}
```

Comment: You need to use `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0):

`@Value` is a feature of Springboot.

These are your options:

1. Let your test cases run as `@SpringBootTest`s.
2. Find ways to set these configuration values yourself (e.g. make them public or package private or add setters for them).